# oracle ctl - add to POSITION a constant

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I don't think if it is possible, but I lose some time in googling but with no results!

I need something like this example:

```
DATA:
(...)195231021(...)

CTL:
TEST        POSITION(37:40) '1'

Result:
0211   (last 3 numbers and append a constant number '1')
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

From [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:358204364266), try using bind variables.

```
TEST        POSITION(37:40) ":TEST || '1'"
```

Comment: WORK GREAT!!! Thanks for fast reply. i only use bind on select and procedures, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can [apply an SQL operator to a field](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226), so this works:

```
test position(37:39) "concat(:test, '1')"
```

You said you only wanted three characters so I changed the range from 37:40 to 37:39, but not sure if you actually want 38:40. (Of course, using the `||` concatenation operator works too, as EatÅPeach's answer shows).